# Fluent NHibernate: ManyToMany Self-referencing mapping

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I need help in creating the correct fluent nh mapping for this kind of scenario:

A category can be a child of one or more categories. Thus, resulting to this entity:

```
public class Category : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    [EntitySignature]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Category> Parents { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Category> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ProductCategory> Products { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        Parents = new List<Category>();
        Children = new List<Category>();
        Products = new List<ProductCategory>();

    }

    public virtual void AddCategoryAsParent(Category parent)
    {
        if (parent != this && !parent.Parents.Contains(this) && !Parents.Contains(parent))
        {
            Parents.Add(parent);
            parent.AddCategoryAsChild(this);
        }
    }

    public virtual void RemoveCategoryAsParent(Category parent)
    {
        if (Parents.Contains(parent))
        {
            Parents.Remove(parent);
            parent.RemoveCategoryAsChild(this);
        }
    }

    public virtual void AddCategoryAsChild(Category child)
    {
        if(child != this && !child.Children.Contains(this) && !Children.Contains(child))
        {
            Children.Add(child);
            child.AddCategoryAsParent(this);
        }
    }

    public virtual void RemoveCategoryAsChild(Category child)
    {
        if(Children.Contains(child))
        {
            Children.Remove(child);
            child.RemoveCategoryAsParent(this);
        }
    }
}
```

My initial mapping is this:

```
public class CategoryMap : ClassMap<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        Id(p => p.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Parents)
            .Table("CategoryParents")
            .ParentKeyColumn("CategoryId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("ParentCategoryId")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .LazyLoad()
            .AsBag();

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Children)
            .Table("CategoryParents")
            .ParentKeyColumn("ParentCategoryId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("CategoryId")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .Inverse()
            .LazyLoad()
            .AsBag();
    }
}
```

The problem with this mapping is whenever I remove a category as a parent or as a child of another category, the resulting SQL statement is this:

```
NHibernate: DELETE FROM CategoryParents WHERE CategoryId = @p0;@p0 = 2
NHibernate: INSERT INTO CategoryParents (CategoryId, ParentCategoryId) VALUES (@p0, @p1);@p0 = 2, @p1 = 3
```

It deletes all the mapping first, then insert the remaining mapping. The proper way is just delete the category parent mapping which this kind of statement:

```
DELETE FROM CategoryParents WHERE CategoryId = @p0 AND ParentCategoryId = @p1;@p0 = 2, @p1=1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I noticed that you are using IAggregateRoot.  Doesn't that go against having more that one parent?

Answer (score 0):

after looking at your mappings I think you are wanting to change your Cascade options. Here is an article which outlines a parent - child relationship between entities. Although it comes from the point of view of having orphaned entities I think you will find the blog helpful. Good luck...

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/02/nhibernatecascadesthedifferentbetweenallalldeleteorphansandsaveupdate.aspx